# Sql transactions vs memory usage vs ini file

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am  building a web application that connects to sql server.
The process is like so : the user log in the site and from that moment there a few connections to the data base, but another thing that arrives from the data base is a representation of the client`s company as an object. the client may change some of the data during the time of the session. and when the session ends(the client closes the browser). the object sent to the data base.
So the question is from the moment that i brought the table to the code behind how should i keep it. in a datatable or ini file. 
Keep in mind that this is browser and i want to keep it as fast as possible.
Thank to you all.

Comment: An `.ini` file? For real?

Comment: Why do you need to store it in memory at all, after transmitting to the browser?

Comment: Because if the client will make some kind of change in the data i would like to save it and to work with the new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the data in the database, and read it from there at every page request. At least, there's where you should start, and only consider caching data in memory if you actualy have any performance problems.

You should not keep a database connection open for the user, you should open a new connection for each request, and close it as soon as possible. The connections are pooled by the system and reused, so it doesn't have to establish a new connection to the database each time you open one, but you should let the system take care of all that.

Data that is changed should be written to the database right away. Holding data in memory and writing it when the session ends has problems with stability and timing. The server doesn't know when the user closes the browser, so the server consideres the session to end a time after the last request from thw user, usually 15 minutes. That means that the data would not be written when the user closes the browser, but up to 15 minutes later. If the user logs in again, the changes would show up after a while. If there is some problems with the server while it holds the data, the data would be lost, and the change would not be saved at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should Use a Database. Not a doubt.

Your users expect (ACID) consistency, as well as the ability to use the webapp with multiple users etc. There's no sense in using an ini file when a database does all that out of the box.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Well, it is the answer to the question...

Comment: And it is a very low quality one at that. A one liner like this should be a comment.

Comment: A simple question deserves a simple answer. It's not a remark, criticism or observation. Really, the English dictionary is quite precise on the concepts of "comment" and "answer" and its definition doesn't include the number of words you should use.

Comment: I am not talking about the "English" definition, but the Stack Overflow _conventions_.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, I'm not trying to be annoying.

Comment: Nor am I. Just trying to keep the site quality up. Dank u wel.